# How to Display time of videoview in android

Tags: android, media, android-videoview

I have a VideoView for Play Video and MediaControler for it

I want Display time of video in textview and change it per time of video

I use this code for Playing video :

```
private void play(String uri) {
    _player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    _player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    _player.setMediaController(mc);
    _player.start();

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    _player.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));


}
```

Answer (score 3):

this method used for convert msec to time and _player.getDuration() is used  on Prepare.

```
    public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if (hours > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }

    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
    MediaPlayer.getDuration()
```

to retrieve the total time of the video. You'll better set a seekbar to retrieve the progress of the video and write it to the textview or better on a chronometer. Or you can simply start the chronometer when the video starts.

Comment: which method in videoview use for getting time in seekbar in every time

Comment: You have to add a seekbar in the layout xml file, than implement the seekbar , to update seekbar progress use:

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a seekbar in the layout xml file, than implement the seekbar , to get real-time progress of the video playing use

```
    MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
```

You have to write a runnable method to update the seekbar every second with this method:

```
    myseekbar.setProgress(myMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition())
```

you have to retrieve the time from getCurrentPosition.

Accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another conversion metod using "TimeUnit" :

```
static String getTimeString(Long millis) {
   return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
}
```